# Chicken population growth

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A chicken starts laying eggs at age 1 year old.
Given enough food, a chicken lays 1 egg per day until 8 years old.

How often can a population of chickens double in population?

Just Curious, Boston.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in a general population the chickens will not all have enough food to lay an egg daily and that too, they'll be different ages. And it seems EXTREMELY unlikely to me that chickens will lay fertilized eggs daily. How often do you see a chicken walking with $77$ chicks behind it?

Take into account sex too. Male chickens cannot lay eggs, only females can.

Consider a population with one male chick and one female chick to begin with, and consider  equal gender rates of hatchlings.

Fastforward $1$ year, the female begins laying eggs. Now, consider the gestation period (or whatever the analogous term is for egg-laying animals). Apparently it takes $21 $ days on average to hatch an egg.

So now, every day starting on (Year/Day ---- First year is $0$) $1/21$ a new chicken is born. By $1/22$ the population has doubled. By the time the first chick of the new generation begins hatching eggs, it is $2/21$ and the population is $367$.

Now from here, the process goes up exponentially. Can you see why? Those $365$ chickens will have maybe $180-190$ females, which will all produce like $50,000$ chickens in the next year.

Honestly, this can't even happen biologically, and if it did, humans would probably exploit the limits of chicken reproduction to make like a 200 pc Mcnugget or something.

Comment: I see why it would be exponential. My sister who breeds chickens says they lay 20% less eggs each year. My idea was to fit an exponential to a delayed differential equation with an arbitrary population size.
They can lay one or sometimes two eggs per day, im considering that to be the limiting factor. chickens are fed as much as they will eat and eggs are removed and incubated.

Comment: but they wouldn't be laying a fertilized egg every day

Comment: They can lay a fertilized egg per day. Its a freak of evolution.

Comment: they must have such a low survival rate, or predators eating chicken eggs @BostonBrooks

Comment: Usually food is scarce enough to limit fertility, but when food is in boom, chickens are evolved to boom in poulation.

Comment: this reminds me of passenger pigeons . heard they used to flock in the billions